# Term of endearment that was formerly somewhat derogatory

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word (phrase if necessary) that means "a term of endearment", but more specifically, a term of endearment that was/is somewhat derogatory and even better, a term that is now accepted by the community (or person) for which it was originally derogatory.

Like the term "ham" for a radio amateur.

> Over the years radio amateurs have adopted the *my word here* "ham" for themselves with seemingly no remorse.

Comment: I presume you would like to avoid the "N-word", as used within the section of society it was (and is) used derogatorily to describe?

Comment: I guess that's another example, but no, my use has nothing to do with the "N-word".

Comment: @Phil M Jones: OP seems to be looking not for a particular derogatory word or examples, but for the *generic term* for such words now accepted by the community (or person) for which is was originally derogatory, am I correct @ OP? As in (random example), "over the years radio amateurs have adopted the [joke term](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22joke+term%22&client=firefox-b&oq=%22joke+term%22&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.3..0i7i30l3j0i30j0i8i30.5056.7589.0.8078.2.2.0.0.0.0.296.541.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.2.539.rqMOV5PCCTI) "ham" for themselves with seemingly no remorse."

Comment: @EnglishStudent You're absolutely right, I misread the question slightly, and thought OP was looking for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say **reclaimed**, but Wikipedia says it should be **re-appropriated**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Reclaimed_words

> Linguistic reclamation is the reappropriation of a pejorative epithet
>   by its target, to turn an insult into a positive term and deny others
>   the ability to define it.
>
> A reclaimed or reappropriated word is a word that was at one time
>   pejorative but has been brought back into acceptable usage, usually
>   starting within the communities that experienced oppression under that
>   word but sometimes also among the general populace as well.[1] (The
>   term "reclaimed word" more often implies usage by a member of the
>   group that is referred.)

Comment: So far I like this - maybe "re-appropriated pejorative" is the right term, if not a single word.